# Aplicar css a un elemento padre

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selectores-css

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<div class="togglearea">
  <div class="toggle">
    <h3>Titulo</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="togglearea">
 <div class="toggle">Titulo 2</div>
</div>
```

He tratado (tanto como por **css** como por **javascript**) de manera fallida que si el `.togglearea` tiene un `h3`, aplicarle al `.togglearea` un `margin-left` de `30px`. Pero solo consigo que se le aplique el cambio al h3 o a todos los .togglearea

Comment: ¿Cómo lo has intentado con JavaScript/jQuery? Debería ser algo realmente simple. Con CSS sin más no se puede hacer porque no hay (de momento) un selector para "padre"

Comment: 1. Obtener todos los toggleareas: `var toggleareas = document.querySelectorAll('.togglearea')`. 2. Iterar los toggleareas: `[].forEach.call(toggleareas, function (area) { ... })`. 3. Para cada togglearea ver si tiene un hijo (directo o no) h3, si es así, añadir margen izquierdo: `if(area.querySelector('h3')) { area.style.marginLeft = '30px'; }`. Por otro lado, me da bastante curiosidad quién le dió favorito..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como te pongo en un comentario, sólo con CSS no se puede hacer porque (de momento) no hay un selector para ancestros o hermanos superiores. Con Javascript/jQuery sería realmente sencillo, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```js
// selecciona todos los h3 que estén dentro de un togglearea
$(".togglearea h3").each(function() {
  // selecciona el .togglearea ancestro del h3 y pone el margen de 30
  $(this).closest(".togglearea").css("margin-left", "30px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="togglearea"><div class="toggle"><h3>Titulo</h3></div></div>
<div class="togglearea"><div class="toggle">Titulo 2</div></div>
```

---

Aunque he dicho que no se puede hacer sólo con CSS, sí que hay una manera de hacerlo sin JS pero deben cumplirse ciertas restricciones:

1. El `h3` debe ser el primer elemento.
2. Requiere que no haya nada más fuera del contenedor del `h3`

La idea sería poner un margen de 30px para TODOS los elementos que haya junto al `h3` usando el selector de hermano `~`. Sería algo como esto:

```css
.togglearea h3,
.togglearea h3 ~ * {
  margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="togglearea"><div class="toggle"><h3>Titulo</h3></div></div>
<div class="togglearea"><div class="toggle">Titulo 2</div></div>
```

Comment: Coloque el CSS pero solo afecta al `h3`, no a `.togglearea` Y el jquery no afecta al `.togglearea` tampoco

Comment: @MarisabelGC ¿puedes compartir tu código para ver qué no funciona? En los ejemplos que pongo arriba funciona correctamente, ¿seguro que no faltó copiar nada?

Comment: Lo probe en un documento aparte y funciona perfecto. Gracias :D