# ¿Cómo aplicar estilo al hijo del siguiente elemento de mi padre?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Al hacer hover en el `header-a` quiero aplicarle estilo al `content-a` o `content-b`, como lo hago al `header-b` en el siguiente ejemplo (también disponible en [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jayroht93/pen/KqeKGO?editors=1100)):

```css
body,
html {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header,
.content {
  background: #4f4b4b;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.child {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.child:hover {
  background: #bcbcbc;
}

.header-a:hover+.header-b {
  background: red;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------*/

.header-a:hover .content .content-a {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-a child">
      header a
    </div>
    <div class="header-b child">
      header b
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-a child">
      content a
    </div>
    <div class="content-b child">
      content b
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <!----->
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Entonces lo que quieres es que si se pone el ratón sobre `header-a`, `content-a` y `content-b` también se pongan en rojo como `header-b`?

Comment: Exacto , eso es lo que quiero. Gracias por comentar.

Comment: Entonces tengo malas noticias: no se puede sólo con CSS porque no hay un selector "padre" (al menos, no de momento). Vas a tener que usar una solución con JavaScript. Mira [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/43796/250) con un problema similar

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, tenia la esperanza de que fuese posible utilizar css.

Comment: si, no sé puede con css puro. No es posible escalar hacia arriba en el DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede solo con CSS, vas a tener que usar JavaScript (ver demo abajo).

CSS es un sistema de estilos en cascada que puede ir "lateralmente" (de manera limitada) o hacia abajo, pero no hacia arriba. Actualmente no existe un selector padre... aunque en los [selectores de nivel 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/) se define un modo para cambiar el sujeto de la regla, con `!`, lo que efectivamente permitiría seleccionar al padre... pero ningún navegador lo soporta (de momento).

Aún así, no te serviría para tu caso en particular, porque no quieres seleccionar al padre sino a un primo, y entonces el operador `!` creo que no serviría porque realmente los elementos que quieres seleccionar no estarían dentro de la secuencia de selectores de la regla.

Deberías definir una nueva clase en CSS y añadirla/quitarla a los elementos que quieras usando JavaScript. Como por ejemplo así:

```js
document.querySelector(".header-a").addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  document.querySelector(".content-a").classList.add("header-a-hover");
  document.querySelector(".content-b").classList.add("header-a-hover");
});

document.querySelector(".header-a").addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  document.querySelector(".content-a").classList.remove("header-a-hover");
  document.querySelector(".content-b").classList.remove("header-a-hover");
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header,
.content {
  background: #4f4b4b;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.child {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.child:hover {
  background: #bcbcbc;
}

.header-a:hover+.header-b {
  background: red;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------*/

.header-a-hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-a child">
      header a
    </div>
    <div class="header-b child">
      header b
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-a child">
      content a
    </div>
    <div class="content-b child">
      content b
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <!----->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede hacer sin la necesidad de usar JS solo debes cambiar esto y listo

```
.header-a:hover .header-b {
  background: red;
 }
```